# C# Active Directory Browsing best practices

Tags: c#, performance, active-directory

Straight to the point, I have a request for a new project on which I have to find the primary and secondary owners for a specific list of Active Directory groups. When I get the array of secondary owners for each group, each of the owners are identified by their "distinguishedName" which led me to use a snippet like this to get the owner's info:

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + distinguishedName))
{
        using (DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
        {
            SearchResult found = dSearch.FindOne();
            if (found != null)
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry userEntry = found.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username: " + userEntry.Properties["namefield"].Value + " : " + userEntry.Properties["emailfield"].Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found with distinguishedName: " + distinguishedName);
            }
        }
}
GC.Collect();
```

I am a little concerned by the performance of this task since I have to get this information at the page loading sequence to check if the logged user is an owner or not. I have other AD browsing task to do and I've been doing some research on best practices with C# and AD and haven't found anything helpful yet so I though that you guys could provide some input on this.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you have distinguished name of an object, you can bind to the object directly. Searching with DirectorySearcher is an excessive operation. Just create DirectoryEntry object and call its RefreshCache method. The fastest performance in ad is provided by classes located under System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace. Also one more optimization can be done: at the start of your program create a DirectoryEntry object and bind, e. g. To rootdse. This will establish ldap connection under the hood. All other queries will use this ldap connection. Keep the object alive until the program finishes

Comment: Awesome Oldovets, how can I mark your reply as an answer?

Comment: Let's leave it as is. Don't care about reputation until I have an opportunity to post comments :)

Comment: Awesome, I want to trouble you with another question. Based on requirements, have to "query" different domains, for example "dom1.com", "dom2.com", "dom3.com". As of now, the applications running under "dom2.com". I've been told that if I "query" AD under "dom1.com" I would access to the other domains. Do you know a way to accomplish this? I was thinking about using impersonation.

Comment: You have several options here: 1. Connect to every domain (using impersonation or pass credentials into the DirectoryEntry constructor, or give to your account appropriate permissions to all of the domains, if these domains have trusts). 2. If all of the domains are located in the same forest, you can query Global Catalog in one domain (by using GC:// instead of LDAP://). Global Catalog stores partial replica of objects from the entire forest, e. g. users from other domains.

Comment: To determine, if an attribute is stored on Global Catalog open ADSIEdit, connect to Schema Naming Context, find the attribute in case, go to its properties and check if isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet is set to TRUE (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23097.active-directory-attributes-in-the-partial-attribute-set.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot and sorry for my late reply.

Comment: oldovets.. My friend! I have to trouble you again :( So, requirements changed (as usual) I have to retrieve users from AD using a "wildcard" search. Something similar to a SharePoint People Picker. If the search query is "evil", I have to look in AD whether the samAccountName, Name, surname, email.. mmm not sure if another property, contains "evil". I am trying something like: ("(&(objectCategory=user)(|(sn=*{0}*)(cn=*{0}*)(email=*{0}*)(mail=*{0}*)(givenName=*{0}*)(displayName=*{0}*)(name=*{0}*)))" in a PrincipalSearcher object, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: Take a look at Ambiguous Name Resolution Active Directory feature. I believe, that's what you're looking for. If your goal is to provide feature like Google Quick Search: when user types "e" and gets a dropdown list of all users, starting with "e", then direct async query to AD is not a good option because of performance. In this case you have to sync AD with local database and retrieve users list from this local database and make query to AD afterwards. However, this is a really complicated solution, which is hard to implement.

Comment: Hello Oldovets, thanks for your suggestions. It's more like getting all users that share something like the search criteria, display them in a list and allow the user to select one of them. Having some sort of "auto-fill helper" is not required. I managed to do it using an AD filter similar to the one I posted before however, we are dealing with data/properties ambiguity between domain. Again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> f you have distinguished name of an object, you can bind to the object directly. Searching with DirectorySearcher is an excessive operation. Just create DirectoryEntry object and call its RefreshCache method. The fastest performance in ad is provided by classes located under System.DirectoryServices.Protocols namespace. Also one more optimization can be done: at the start of your program create a DirectoryEntry object and bind, e. g. To rootdse. This will establish ldap connection under the hood. All other queries will use this ldap connection. Keep the object alive until the program finishes

Credit to: [oldovets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826115/oldovets)